# How to use multiple SuperpoweredFilter types in a singular audiosystem (SuperpoweredAudioIO)

Tags: android, java-native-interface, native, superpowered

About the SuperpoweredFilter (being an analogue filter). Is it possible to have two instances for highpass and lowpass filter types in one audio system (SuperpoweredAudioIO)?
Because I have tried different methods but the last filter type's instance declared only gets audible at runtime.
Please help

This is my declaration of both instances;

```
filter = new SuperpoweredFilter(SuperpoweredFilter_Resonant_Highpass, samplerate);
filterb = new SuperpoweredFilter(SuperpoweredFilter_Resonant_Lowpass, samplerate);


audioSystem = new SuperpoweredAndroidAudioIO(samplerate, buffersize, false, true, audioProcessing, this, -1, SL_ANDROID_STREAM_MEDIA, buffersize * 2);

           filterb->setResonantParameters(floatToFrequency(1.0f), 0.2f);
           filter->setResonantParameters(floatToFrequency(1.0f), 0.2f);              //resonance
           filterb->enable(true);
           filter->enable(true);

       playerA->play(false);
```

Also in the audioprocessing method, I called

```
filterb->process(stereoBuffer, stereoBuffer, numberOfSamples);  
filter->process(stereoBuffer, stereoBuffer, numberOfSamples);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear What you mean with

> only gets audible at runtime

Do you call

```
filterb->process(stereoBuffer, stereoBuffer, numberOfSamples);  
filter->process(stereoBuffer, stereoBuffer, numberOfSamples);
```

in the main "process" method?

Using the above calling sequence, however, if you set both filters Fc to 1.0 (that is 20kHz) you will have a situation like:
Lowpass-> block all frequencies above 20kHz (i.e.: no audible effect)
then
Highpass-> block all frequencies below 20kHz (i.e.: total frequencies cut off)
so you'll have almost no signal in output!
Did you try to change the Fc dynamically?

Comment: Yes, I tried it. I'm sorry, I am not very familiar with the native side of DSP and some terms you are using such as (FC). Yes, I called the 

filterb->process(stereoBuffer, stereoBuffer, numberOfSamples); 
filter->process(stereoBuffer, stereoBuffer, numberOfSamples);  

Can you please suggest a way/snippet of doing this?

Comment: Fc is the "cutoff frequency" of a filter, which is the frequency where the filter start to cut higher (lowpass) or lower (highpass) frequencies of the signal.
Start from CrossExample. It already implements a filter whose Fc is controlled by a slider. You can duplicate the code for adding a second slider and control the two filters Fc in an indipendent way.